# SVD of Vandermonde matrix in MATLAB inaccurate?

Tags: matlab, svd

I have noticed that the SVD of a Vandermonde matrix in MATLAB does not always yield correct results. I have tried the following example:

```
C=fliplr(vander(linspace(7,8,20)));
[U,Sigma,V]=svd(C);
Cnew=U*Sigma*V';
E=abs(Cnew-C)./abs(C);
```

The mean relative error in the second column is 7% but there are elements with errors 100-200%. All other columns seem to have much lower errors, which also seems unnatural.

I have Matlab version 6.5, I don't know whether later versions are more accurate. Is there a way to compute this SVD more accurate with Matlab, or do I have to resort to external numerical libraries? (I was thinking of LAPACK, but I am not sure whether Matlab uses the algorithms of LAPACK too).

Thank you very much!

PS: By researching in the internet I found out that Vandermonde matrices are especially tricky (see e.g. http://math.mit.edu/~plamen/files/chebvand.pdf and http://www-math.mit.edu/~plamen/talks/mit02.pdf ).

PS2: The actual problem I am facing is to find the SVD of `C=[A,-B]`, where

```
A=VAN(1:N,1:Q);
B=diag(data)*VAN(1:N,1:Q+1);
```

where `VAN=fliplr(vander(linspace(7,8,N)));` and `data` is a an array of N values measured or calculated at the points of `linspace(7,8,N)`. `Q` should be smaller than `N`.

However, since I cannot even find the SVD of `VAN` correctly, I figured this would be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, Vandermonde matrices can be tricky. R2013a has the same behavior. Your example matrix contains values over a huge range (`eps(max(C(:)))` is `32` but `min(C(:))` is `1`). Are variable precision arithmetic or symbolic solutions acceptable? Because of the range of your values it may matter what you're doing with the output of `svd`.

Comment: @horchler : Do you think that symbolic calculations could help? I need a few significant digits for ALL singular values, and these values span a huge range. The actual problem I am facing is more complicated (see edited question, PS2).

Comment: They could. The problem I was alluding to is when you need to convert back to double precision, which could . Try `C = vpa(C)` or `C = sym(C)` (these are slightly different -print them to see) where `C` is your Vandermonde matrix. Calculations may be a bit slower and certain functions might not support these datatypes. If you try to convert all of `U`, `Sigma`, and `V` back to double precision (using `double`) you'll have large errors again if you use them to calculate `Cnew`. So you may need to carry them through to your later calculations.

Comment: @horchler : Thanks a lot for the tip, I might try it (my version of MATLAB does not include the symbolic toolbox; do you know whether Octave supports symbolic svd?). Anyway, I have found another way around my original problem, by scaling the independent variable (vector input to the Vandermonde matrix) to a small interval around 1, so that the matrix `C` does not have a large dynamic range.